# como colocar dos value a un select option

Tags: javascript, select, options

**Antes realice una pregunta con imágenes esta vez la realice con código**

Espero me puedan ayudar con mi pregunta ya que no soy experto en el tema y se los agradecería mucho.

Quiero que un option de un select cuente con dos value, por ejemplo en el select 1 la opción 1 contenga un value que diga value1="1" (este ya lo ocupo para la función en JS) y poder poner otro value2="10". Esto para poder realizar una suma al final

la parte de JS ya esta resuelta, esta funciona que dependiendo lo que selecciona manda un texto y el segundo value lo ocuparía para extraer el valor y hacer una variable donde se acumule y al final mandar a sumar con la siguiente variable y en la parte del párrafo imprimir la variable resultante

```
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
 
        <script>
        function Select1(objeto)
        {
            var indice=objeto.selectedIndex;
 
            if(objeto.value==1||objeto.value==2)
            {

                var resultado="La opción 1 o 2 seleccionada es "+objeto.options[indice].text;
                document.getElementById("resultado1").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
            if(objeto.value==3)
            {
 
                var resultado="La opción 3 seleccionada es "+objeto.options[indice].text;
                document.getElementById("resultado1").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
            if(objeto.value==0){
 
                var resultado="NO A SELECCIONADO NADA";
                document.getElementById("resultado1").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
        }

        function Select2(objeto)
        {
            var indice=objeto.selectedIndex;
 
            if(objeto.value==1||objeto.value==2)
            {
 
                var resultado="La opcion 1 ó 2 es "+objeto.options[indice].text;
                document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
            if(objeto.value==3)
            {
 
                var resultado="La opcion tres es "+objeto.options[indice].text;
                document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
            if(objeto.value==0){
 
                var resultado="NO A SELECCIONADO NADA";
                document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML=resultado;
            }
        }


        </script>
    </head>
 
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="miSelect1" id="miSelect1" onchange="Select1(this)">
                <option value="0">selecciona</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 10-->
                <option value="1">Numero 1</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 15-->
                <option value="2">Numero 2</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 12-->
                <option value="3">Numero 3</option>
            </select>
 
        </form>

        <div id="resultado1">primero</div><br>

        <form>
            <select name="miSelect2" id="miSelect2" onchange="Select2(this) ">
                <option value="0">selecciona</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 5-->
                <option value="1">Objeto1</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 2-->
                <option value="2">Objeto2</option>
                <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 13-->
                <option value="3">Objeto3</option>
            </select>
 
        </form>

        <div id="resultado2">segundo</div>
        <p>La suma de los objetos escogidos es: </p> <!-- aquí pondria la suma de los dos select-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: prueba con data, es decir a la option le pones un data con el segundo value 
... <option data-value2='10' value='1'>Opcion 1 </option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con data, es decir a la option le pones un data con el segundo value

```
... <option data-value2='10' value='1'>Opcion 1 </option>
```

Es decir así:

```
<form>
    <select name="miSelect1" id="miSelect1" onchange="Select1(this)">
        <option value="0" >selecciona</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 10-->
        <option value="1" data-value2="10">Numero 1</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 15-->
        <option value="2" data-value2="15">Numero 2</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 12-->
        <option value="3" data-value2="12">Numero 3</option>
    </select>

</form>

<div id="resultado1">primero</div><br>

<form>
    <select name="miSelect2" id="miSelect2" onchange="Select2(this) ">
        <option value="0" >selecciona</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 5-->
        <option value="1" data-value2="5">Objeto1</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 2-->
        <option value="2" data-value2="2">Objeto2</option>
        <!-- este value tendria que tener el valor de 13-->
        <option value="3" data-value2="13">Objeto3</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

y en el JAVASCRIPT tomas como en la documentacion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38519791/how-to-get-data-attribute-of-option-tag-in-javascript/38519877 el valor del value2 así:

```
mySelect.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute("data-value2")
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió de mucho